# How to drag and sort in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am fairly new to React native, and I am looking for a good way to have a sortable list. To my knowledge, I was unable to find any good examples that I could replicate (though there is one repo being worked on). Without the HTML5 drag and drop, what is the basic strategy for drag and sort with React Native? Thank you.

Comment: Have you already checked this one:
[react-native-SortableList](https://github.com/hayeah/react-native-SortableList)
If not, maybe try it. I think, they also describe their solution in the readme and you can read their code.

Comment: Looking for a production-ready solution for this as well. Can't seem to find it but I'll try and post back here anything that I land on. Were you able to solve this, considering it was a year and a half ago? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

### [React Native Sortable List](https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list)

I tested out about 5 different solutions, none of which worked very well, especially on Android, so I invested a day of programming to update the most promising, which was [React Native Sortable List](https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list).

Now it works fantastic on both iOS and on Android. Here's an [animation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list/master/demo.gif) of it in action on both platforms *(click the image to watch the gif)*.

[image: Animation]

Comment: So that was written by you?

Comment: @KyleKhalaf No, the project was started by [gitim](https://github.com/gitim). I just updated the library to get the Android platform up to parity with iOS.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter What were the other five that you tried? SortableListView by Dean McPherson appears to also be in popular use, but is buggy when put in nested views.

Comment: Does it support nested lists?

Comment: @Aspen I can't recall which ones but if you do a simple Google you'd likely find them.

Comment: @PerQuestedAronsson Not at the time of writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested a lot of packages but they were all buggy and couldn't achieve what I wanted to do.

So I wrote my own sortable list (vertical and horizontal). Feel free to check it out and leave a comment. It's written in Javascript so it's compatible with any type of project.

Here is an example of it:

[Sortable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68537299/sortable-list-for-react-native)

[image]

Comment: Showing Page not found!

Comment: First of all, thanks for your effort. Really appreciate it. I found your git repo, and got a look from it. It was good. But I am looking for something which used react-native-reanimated v2 api's.

Comment: Please update the link. It is not an active link